# Best way of validating if a given JSON key and value in one file is available in another file

Tags: c#, .net, json, logic, implementation

I am finding it hard to implement a logic which will check for if a certain key-value (together) in one file has an actual exactly similar key-value in another file

i have one file as below ,

```
[
{
"IdInOne": "001",
"NameInOne": "Name_2"
},
{
"IdInOne": "002",
"NameInOne": "Name_3"
}
]
```

and the other as

```
[
{
"IdInTwo": "001",
"NameInTwo": "Name_1"
},
{
"IdInTwo": "001",
"NameInTwo": "Name_2"
},
{
"IdInTwo": "001",
"NameInTwo": "Name_3"
},
{
"IdInTwo": "002",
"NameInTwo": "Name_4"
}
]
```

in this example there is one entry where "IdInOne": "001","NameInOne": "Name_2" matches an exactly same value in the second JSON file. So in that case I will print a success message

but there is no match in the second JSON file where "IdInOne": "002","NameInOne": "Name_3" hence I want to print in the Console an unsuccessful message

Can anyone help me on this please ? Any idea of what kinda algorithm I need ?

Comment: The algorithm is just what you described. Load contents of both files in two different array of items and then find if any item from one list exists in another. You might need to create POCO classes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could first make two model classes representing your JSON:

```
public class One
{
    public string IdInOne { get; set; }
    public string NameInOne { get; set; }
}

public class Two
{
    public string IdInTwo { get; set; }
    public string NameInTwo { get; set; }
}
```

Then deserialize the JSON with these classes using [Newtonsoft Json.NET](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json). Since we are dealing with JSON arrays, we can deserialize into `List<T>`.

```
var json1 = "[{\"IdInOne\": \"001\",\"NameInOne\": \"Name_2\"},{\"IdInOne\": \"002\",\"NameInOne\": \"Name_3\"}]";
var json2 = "[{\"IdInTwo\": \"001\",\"NameInTwo\": \"Name_1\"},{\"IdInTwo\": \"001\",\"NameInTwo\": \"Name_2\"},{\"IdInTwo\": \"001\",\"NameInTwo\": \"Name_3\"},{\"IdInTwo\": \"002\",\"NameInTwo\": \"Name_4\"}]";

var deserializedJson1 = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<One>>(json1);
var deserializedJson2 = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Two>>(json2);
```

Then you can simply compare using [`Any()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.any?view=netframework-4.8) from LINQ:

```
foreach (var one in deserializedJson1)
{
    if (deserializedJson2.Any(two => two.IdInTwo == one.IdInOne &&
                              two.NameInTwo == one.NameInOne))
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"Match found with {one.IdInOne} and {one.NameInOne}");
    } else
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"No match found with {one.IdInOne} and {one.NameInOne}");
    }
}
```

Which Outputs:

```
Match found with 001 and Name_2
No match found with 002 and Name_3
```

Another implementation could be to deserialize into tuples, then simply convert the *twos* to a `HashSet<T>` and use it for lookups. Having a hashset improves the lookups from O(N) to O(1), and could provide a performance increase for larger sets of data. [`HashSet<T>.Contains(T)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.hashset-1.contains?view=netframework-4.8) is a O(1) method.

```
var ones = JsonConvert
    .DeserializeObject<List<One>>(json1)
    .Select(x => (x.IdInOne, x.NameInOne));

var lookups = JsonConvert
    .DeserializeObject<List<Two>>(json2)
    .Select(x => (x.IdInTwo, x.NameInTwo))
    .ToHashSet();

foreach (var (IdInOne, NameInOne) in ones)
{
    if (lookups.Contains((IdInOne, NameInOne)))
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"Match found with {IdInOne} and {NameInOne}");
    } else
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"No match found with {IdInOne} and {NameInOne}");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use Newtonsoft and use a POCO class to parse your two models and compare after that both instances properties.

See this example of how to deserialize a json

https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/DeserializeObject.htm

You can use reflection to iterate for all the properties on the second object asking for the value of the property to compare.
This is useful when you don't know the name of the property to compare with.

Hope this helps

Comment: Yes , that part is sorted . Any idea how I can compare the  two ?

Comment: You can use reflection for this kind of comparison, to get the property from one object and then query the same property name if it is contained in some way on one of the properties of the second object

Comment: Never heard of Reflections actually .. thanks will check it out . 
this is what you are talking about right ? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/reflection

Comment: yes, the content is more extensive but that is a good starting point